# Makemigrations ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

When I'm trying to manage.py makemigrations there is a error:

My models are:

```
class Burger(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mt = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    img = models.ImageField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    bid = models.ForeignKey('Burger', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Burger123\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Burger123\BURRGER\models.py", line 15, in <module>
    class Comment(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 158, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 299, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 703, in contribute_to_class
    super(ForeignObject, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name, virtual_only=virtual_only)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 308, in contribute_to_class
    lazy_related_operation(resolve_related_class, cls, self.remote_field.model, field=self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 85, in lazy_related_operation
    return apps.lazy_model_operation(partial(function, **kwargs), *model_keys)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 83, in <genexpr>
    model_keys = (make_model_tuple(m) for m in models)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\utils.py", line 13, in make_model_tuple
    app_label, model_name = model.split(".")
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

My `INSTALLED_APPS` setting is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'BURRGER.apps.BurrgerConfig'
]
```

`BurrgerConfig`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class BurrgerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'BURRGER'
    label = 'my.burger'
```

I deleted line `bid = models.ForeignKey('Burger', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and makemigrations ended without errors. But I totally need this line in my code so the question is still open.

Comment: Instead of posting images of text, *post the actual text*. along with what you have tried/researched.

Comment: Can you try **manage.py makemigration djang_app_name** ? After a first migration, you must type the app name.

Comment: Please don't remove the traceback when you edit your question -- it shows what the error is and where it is occurring.

Comment: Again, what have you tried/researched yourself so far. What this error comes back to as you could see in *any* of the related questions you can see on the right is you most likely have an erroneous comma somewhere. (Kudos on the patience, Alasdair)

Comment: The problem is in your `AppConfig` class, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label) in your app config should not contain a dot. You could do something like:

```
class BurrgerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'BURRGER'
    label = 'burger'
```

Your code is more confusing because you have mispelled 'BURRGER' in your code and directory name. The usual approach in Python/Django would be

```
burger - directory name, name and lable in app config class
Burger - model name
BurgerConfig - App Config class name
```